# Is there any conditional formatting in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working on a countdown using moment.js.
It would be nice if I could have conditional formatting.

here is what I have for now

```
var count_down = moment().hour(23).min(30);
alert( count_down.format('H[h ]m[min ]s[s]') );
```

that displays:

> 0h 43min 20s

---

I would like to know if there is a format expression that would do

```
var format = 'H[h ]m[min ]s[s]';
if (count_down.hour() === 0)
   format = 'm[min ]s[s]';
alert( count_down.format(format) );
```

displaying:

> 43min 20s

I have not seen anything like it in the doc though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `moment` object represents a time-of-day, which does not make sense for a count-down.  You should use moment's [`duration` object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for this purpose instead.

Moment doesn't yet have direct support for formatting durations, so you would do something like this:

```
var d = moment.duration('23:30');
var s = (d.hours() > 0 ? d.hours() + 'h ' : '')
        + d.minutes() + 'min '
        + d.seconds() + 's';
```

Alternatively, you can try the [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/) plugin, but you still will have to handle the conditional evaluation yourself.

Comment: thank you. I was not aware of the duration object :)